# Why I can't ping anything using this Ubuntu machine?

Tags: networking, ping

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 VM that is in the network of a client that is unable to perform ping.

I have tried to perform:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

I discovered that I can ping another machine in the same network but I can't ping adresses on Internet (outside the network)

but I am obtaining no response.

What could be the problem? How to investigate and try to fix it?

Comment: Seems like you have conclusively demonstrated that the problem is not `ping`.

Comment: @user535733 yes but...what could be the network problem generating this issue?

Comment: Could be your gateway settings, your DNS settings, the router settings, an ISP policy, etc. So many possibilities, a few of which are on your machine...and many of which are not. Can other machines on this LAN ping out? Can the machine you are troubleshooting use `wget` to fetch a sample http file within the LAN? If so, can it fetch a sample http file from the wider internet?